# Django : get_or_create Raises duplicate entry with together_unique

Tags: python, django, django-models

model example

```
class Example(Stat):
    numeric = models.IntegerField(...) 
    date = models.DateField( auto_now_add=True,...) #auto_now_add=True was the problem

    class Meta:
       unique_together = ('numeric','date')
```

)

If 72 and '2011-08-07' is already stored

```
Example.object.get_or_create(numeric=72,date='2011-08-07')
```

raises

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '72-2011-08-07'
```

the question is why `get_or_create` raises the `IntegrityError`, thats the idea of using 
`get_or_create`.

Not sure if this is a bug, I opened a ticket https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16587

Comment: sorry if wasn't clear the question. I edited the question, hope is better now

Comment: Does just a plain `get` with the same EXACT arguments as `get_or_create` return the item?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It appears your problem is with there being more columns you're not including in your `get_or_create`, see i.e. [this thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/django-updates@googlegroups.com/msg19447.html) on a Django mailing list.

You need to use the `defaults` parameter of `get_or_create` as described in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create), or specify values for all columns, for `get_or_create` to match correctly.

Comment: I understand that type of use I would need defaults,but my params in get_or_create are the entire fields avaidable in the class. Anyways that information helped a lot. Also if I remove the unique_together the get_or_create works.

Comment: `get_or_create` is also partially case sensitive -- if they have different case, it won't find the match, but you might still hit the uniqueness constraint.

Comment: I solved the problem reading your answer. DateField was using  auto_now_add=True , so I avoided some important information in my question. To solve auto_now_add=False is working now

Comment: The part of the defaults is often skipped over, and is a common source of errors.

Comment: @llazzaro Why can't 'DateField was using auto_now_add=True' be added to your defaults?

Comment: I'm setting my defaults and still getting this integrity error :/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your autoincrement counter is not the reason of this error.

Postgresql solution of resetting primary key autoincrement might be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55024610/7127824)