# Django - get_or_create not working

Tags: python, django, django-models

can you help me understand why this code causes a duplicate entry (IntegrityError)?

I'm on Django 1.2.

```
(row, is_new) = MyModel.objects.get_or_create(field1=1)
row.other_field = 2
row.save()
```

I do have a unique constraint on field1.  If there is a row where field1=1, everything works fine, Django does a "get".

If there is not a row where field1=1, it looks like Django is creating that row which is ok.  But why won't it let me save it?

Update:

If it helps, here is MyModel:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    field1 = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True)
    other_field = models.CharField(max_length=765)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'project_crosses_suppl_FO'
```

field1 is a foreign key to another table.  But I didn't make a model in Django for that table so I don't tell Django it's a foreign key.

Comment: Does MyModel have foreign field? Can you post code of MyModel?

Comment: [This similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974463/django-get-or-create-raises-duplicate-entry-with-together-unique) might help you.

Comment: @agf.  I don't understand what the resolution was in that question, or how the problem is justified.  It sounds like a bug to me.  I think I'll give up on get_or_create and do a work around :-(

Comment: can you set a charfield to an integer?  does that work?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that's a reasonably faithful representation of your real code, not surprisingly it's not Django that's busted, it's your model.

You've overridden the automatic primary key field with your own `id` field, but neglected to make it an autoincrement. So the database is not using a new value for the PK, hence the integrity error.

Unless you have a really good reason, you should let Django deal with the PK field itself.

Comment: Oh that's a good point.  It's an existing table that I can't change.  That's why I'm telling Django what the primary key is.  So what do I change exactly?  The column "id" in the MySQL table is actually set to auto-increment.  Do I need to tell Django it's an auto-increment field?

Answer (score 3):

get_or_create sounds busted to me.  I'm just doing this work around:

```
rows = MyModel.objects.filter(field1=1)
row = rows[0] if rows else MyModel(field1=1)
row.other_field = 2
row.save()
```

Answer (score 2):

Get or Create returns a tuple of results even if your field you use is set as primary key or unique.

So in your case: row is a tuple with one object, hence this should work for you:

```
(row, is_new) = MyModel.objects.get_or_create(field1=1)
row[0].other_field = 2
row[0].save()
```