# How can i set a auto increment value to default value which i like

Tags: postgresql-9.2

I had a table with columns **`serial`** i want to keep this column as **`auto-increment`** from value 1001...

TABLEA

```
SERIAL NO   | EMPID |   EMPNAME   |    SAL
============================================

1001            1        XXXX         1000

1002            2        YYYY         2000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342440/reset-auto-increment-counter-in-postgres) you can achieve this by issuing:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE TABLEA_serial_seq RESTART WITH 1001;
```