# Django Reset auto-increment

Tags: django, django-admin

So I have a Django application going and in my models.py I have a field that has `models.AutoField(primary_key=True)`. I went into the admin site and deleted some rows off the table, yet when creating a new object the auto-incremented value picked up where it left off instead of going back to 1.

Is there any way I can reset this? I've already tried removing the field, running my migrations, then adding my field back.

Comment: Which database do you use?

Comment: SQLite (when I run python3 manage.py dbshell, SQLite is the db)

Comment: WHY would you want to do this actually ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the following command if you are using PostgreSQL.

```
python manage.py sqlsequencereset AppName| psql DatabaseName
```

change the **AppName** to your application name and **DatabaseName** to your database name.

check also [Django reset auto-increment pk/id field for production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32531677/django-reset-auto-increment-pk-id-field-for-production)

Comment: I haven't changed the DB I'm using and I believe it's SQLite. Anyway to do it in the dbshell with SqLite?

Comment: from **dbshell** you can use `ALTER TABLE <table_name> AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;`