# Django Django administration shows more objects then the actual datapoints

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-admin

I have created a Django model and uploaded some data, around 90 data point. I deleted and uploaded these data points multiple times for testing purposes. I notice my  Django admin showing object number much higher then the actual data point present in the database.

`PeptideSeq object (695)`

While the total data point I have around 90. Is these normal  behavior or is there a way to correct this issue and start the count from zero when you delete all objects. I used Django admin GUI to delete objects.

Thanks!

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32531677/django-reset-auto-increment-pk-id-field-for-production and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27735375/django-model-instances-primary-keys-do-not-reset-to-1-after-all-instances-are-de

Answer (score 0):

For each model django add a auto field by default named id which is auto increment primary key.
When you add a record it adds id 1,2,3,… and so on. Now consider you have id 1-90 for your 90 records and flush the table then the new record will be added with id 91. If you want to reset the id to 1 you should truncate table