# In Django model how can I create a field that resets to 1 on flush?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

my model :

```
class User(models.Model) :
    """Model for a Person"""
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    groups = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=7, blank=True, null=True)
```

This class already has an id primary key. I have following entries in my database:

```
In [23]: temp = User.objects.all()

In [24]: temp
Out[24]: [<User: testid@test.com>, <User: test2@test.com>]

In [25]: temp[0].id
Out[25]: 15

In [26]: temp[1].id
Out[26]: 16
```

Now When I run :

```
python manage.py flush
```

Here is how my database looks:

```
In [27]: User.objects.all()
Out[27]: []
```

Now when I add a new user it has id after **16** as from previous output.

```
In [28]: x = User(email="test3@faf.com")

In [29]: x.save()

In [30]: x.id
Out[30]: 17
```

I have read the answers [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27735375/django-model-instances-primary-keys-do-not-reset-to-1-after-all-instances-are-de), that primary key continue after where they have left. I am also fine with that and do not want to alter this behaviour. Instead, what I want is to create another field that starts again from 1 after the db has been flushed. I have some logic that relies on this behaviour. Please tell me a way so that I can create an Integer Type auto-increment field which resets to 1 on flush.

I am using sqlite3 as database.

Answer (score 1):

you can run this command in `manage.py dbshell`

```
delete from your_table;    
delete from sqlite_sequence where name='your_table';
```

this will reset the auto increment , and you can easily convert this into a command . [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-management-commands/)  is more info about it.

Which would look something like this

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def add_arguments(self, parser):

        parser.add_argument('table_name',type=str)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        table_name = options['table_name']
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("delete from {}".format(table_name))
        cursor.execute("delete from from sqlite_sequence where name='{}'".format(table_name))
```

Also keep in mind the table name would be `app_name`+`_`+`model_name`.
So for eg. if you have an app named `work` and a model named `employee` inside then the default table name in the sqlite will be `work_employee`.

Note : i havent tested the code.