# postgresql postgis : defining a new subzone index consistent with the old one

Tags: postgresql

Here is my problem: I had a polygon layer with an index which looks like this:

`id, population
100, 26
200, 12
300, 45
...`

I edited the polygon layer and divided some of the polygons into smaller polygons (approximately 3-7 subpolygons). I already took care of having my data splitted between subzones (according to population density). So now I have this:

`id, population
100, 22
100, 1
100, 3
200, 6
200, 6`

I would like to create a new index that reflects the old one. For instance:

`oldId, newId, population
100, 100, 22
100, 101, 1
100, 102, 3
200, 200, 6
200, 201, 6`

Things I tried:
Defining a sequence:

`DROP SEQUENCE IF EXISTS increment_id;
CREATE TEMP SEQUENCE increment_id INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 0;
SELECT 
    id, 
    id+nextval('increment_id') AS new_id 
FROM polygon_mapping  WHERE id = 100;`

THis works well for a single id to rename (the WHERE clause), but I don't know how to restart the sequence for every id.

I made some thinking around using the 'lag' function to compare current id with previous id. But I don't manage make it work.

Any suggestions?
Thank you

ps: I went through
[Reset auto increment counter in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342440/reset-auto-increment-counter-in-postgres)
where they reset the SEQUENCE but I don't manage to make it work in a SELECT clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using [generate_series()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html)?

```
SELECT id, generate_series(id,id + count(*)) AS newid 
FROM polygon_mapping GROUP BY id;
```

If you want to select additional attributes, use a subquery and group the attributes using [array_agg](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html), than select the values from the array in the primary query:

```
SELECT id, 
       generate - 1 + id AS newid,
       population_array[generate] 
FROM (
   SELECT id,
          generate_series(1,count(*)) AS generate,
          array_agg(population) AS population_array 
   FROM polygon_mapping GROUP BY id
) AS foo ORDER BY newid,id;
```

Comment: Hey!
Thank you for answering, it is very close to what I am looking for !  

The thing is: I am also trying to keep the rest of the information (there are other columns :

id, data1, data2...
100, 0.5, 0.2

And you method won't let me have this additional information.
Do you have any clue how to get it?

Comment: btw: I am a newbe with 1 reputation score, so I can't upvote your answer which is usefull :(

Comment: Do you mean, the same informations should appear redundantly in every "sub" polygon? Maybe you can update your question with more complete example

Comment: Good suggestion: I updated the question so it reflects better what I am trying to achieve.
Thank you for the suggestion: I was trying to make the question simple, I turned out making it a different question...

Comment: Thank you very much Tommaso, it is working perfectly !
(I am marking the answer as correct, but I still can't upvote your answer because i have no reputation points)