# Sequelize with Postgres throw Validation error

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I have tried to create a device using `Device.create({...})`, but see the following error:

```
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "devices" ("id","name","price","rating","img","createdAt","updatedAt","BrandId","TypeId") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8) RETURNING "id","name","price","rating","img","createdAt","updatedAt","BrandId","TypeId";
Error: SequelizeUniqueConstraintError: Validation error
    at Function.internal (file:///.../react+node.js/server/build/api/error/ApiError.js:14:16)    
    at file:///.../react+node.js/server/build/api/controllers/deviceController.js:52:31
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at rejected (file:///.../react+node.js/server/build/api/controllers/deviceController.js:5:65)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Definition of User:

```js
// this I use just for typing but added just in case
export class Device extends Model<InferAttributes<Device>, InferCreationAttributes<Device>> {
  declare id: CreationOptional<number>

  declare name: string
  declare price: number
  declare rating: CreationOptional<number>
  declare img: string

  declare TypeId: ForeignKey<Type['id']>
  declare BrandId: ForeignKey<Brand['id']>

  declare createdAt: CreationOptional<Date>
  declare updatedAt: CreationOptional<Date>
}

Device.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    price: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    rating: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      defaultValue: 0
    },
    img: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    createdAt: DataTypes.DATE,
    updatedAt: DataTypes.DATE
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'devices'
  }
)

Device.hasMany(Rating)
Rating.belongsTo(Device)

Device.hasMany(BasketDevice)
BasketDevice.belongsTo(Device)

Device.hasMany(DeviceInfo, { as: 'info' })
DeviceInfo.belongsTo(Device)
```

But:

1. I could create devices before
2. I can still create other types of data(that do not need to upload an image)
3. I used the debugger to see all data types that go as parameters to `create` and saw that they were correct.

[image: debugger values example]

My `createDevice` function

```js
async (req: deviceRequestCreate, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> {
  const { BrandId, TypeId, info, name, price } = req.body

  if (!BrandId) return next(ApiError.internal('BrandId is required'))
  if (!TypeId) return next(ApiError.internal('TypeId is required'))
  if (!name) return next(ApiError.internal('Name is required'))
  if (!price) return next(ApiError.internal('Price is required'))

  const numberBrandId = parseInt(BrandId)
  const numberTypeId = parseInt(TypeId)
  const numberPrice = parseInt(price)

  if (!req.files) return next(ApiError.internal('Image is not uploaded'))
  const { img } = req.files

  if (Array.isArray(img)) {
    return next(ApiError.internal('Uploading more than one image is not supported yet'))
  }

  const fileName = uuidv4() + '.jpg'
  img.mv(path.resolve('src/static/' + fileName))

  // HERE ERROR OCCURRED
  const newDevice = await Device.create({ name, price: numberPrice, TypeId: numberTypeId, BrandId: numberBrandId, img: fileName })

  res.json(newDevice)
}
```

I make post requests through the Insomnia:
[image: Insomnia post request showcase]
I have `Content-Type` in the header for `multipart/form-data` and authorization token.

From what I understand, it is a problem with types. But I do not know where.

What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unhandled rejection SequelizeUniqueConstraintError: Validation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40709409/unhandled-rejection-sequelizeuniqueconstrainterror-validation-error)

Comment: No(. I updated my question with a picture of debugger values

Answer (score 1):

It was probably some problem with the types on the server. It is my own server, so I just deleted the cascade of Devices. And created again. All work)