# Generate custom number for primary key and validation

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have following schema:

```
  @primary_key false
  schema "companies" do
    field :number,         :integer, primary_key: true
    field :name,           :string
    field :street,         :string
    field :zipcode,        :integer
    field :location,       :string
    field :phone,          :integer
    field :company_class,  :string
    field :country_iso,    :string
    field :email,          :string
    field :password,       :string, virtual: true
    field :password_hash,  :string
    has_many :contacts,    Busiket.Contact, on_delete: :delete_all

    timestamps
  end

  def register(struct, params \\ %{}) do

  end
```

How can I generate a number for field `number`, when a changeset will be create through the register function?

How can I validate first the database, if the number is already available or not, to avoid duplication.

Comment: Any reason you're not using an auto increment key for this?

Comment: Yes, because I want to use number as id. Is it not a good practice?

Comment: What do you mean by "generate a number" then? An integer key with auto increment would create records with values 0, 1, 2, ...

Comment: I will generate a number, that will always have 7 numbers, for example: `1000554` or `4117455'.

Comment: That will be as a customer number. @Dogbert it is a good practice?

Comment: I think it might be better to set the initial value of the auto increment sequence to `1000000` in the migration. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342440/reset-auto-increment-counter-in-postgres. When you reach `9999999` it'll continue with 8 digit integers (`10000000..99999999`).

Comment: Can I do that with ecto?

Comment: Yes. I'll post an answer with details as soon as I get time.

Comment: Thanks so much @Dogbert, where do you know all the thinks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to create a column that starts at 1000000 and automatically assigns a unique value which is roughly equivalent to the previous value + 1 (roughly because an id might be "skipped" because of failed transactions and possibly some other cases).

This answer is specific to PostgreSQL as it uses the PostgreSQL specific `setval` and `pg_get_serial_sequence` functions.

Migration:

```
defmodule MyApp.Repo.Migrations.CreateCompany do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def up do
    create table(:companies, primary_key: false) do
      add :number, :serial, primary_key: true
      timestamps()
    end
    execute "select setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('companies', 'number'), 999999)"
  end

  def down do
    drop table(:companies)
  end
end
```

Model:

```
defmodule MyApp.Company do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  @primary_key false
  schema "companies" do
    field :number, :integer, primary_key: true, read_after_writes: true

    timestamps()
  end
end
```

Demo:

```
iex(1)> Repo.insert! %Company{}
[debug] QUERY OK db=2.7ms queue=0.1ms
INSERT INTO "companies" ("inserted_at","updated_at") VALUES ($1,$2) RETURNING "number" [{{2016, 12, 5}, {15, 57, 44, 0}}, {{2016, 12, 5}, {15, 57, 44, 0}}]
%MyApp.Company{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "companies">,
 inserted_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-12-05 15:57:44>, number: 1000000,
 updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-12-05 15:57:44>}
iex(2)> Repo.insert! %Company{}
[debug] QUERY OK db=4.5ms
INSERT INTO "companies" ("inserted_at","updated_at") VALUES ($1,$2) RETURNING "number" [{{2016, 12, 5}, {15, 57, 44, 0}}, {{2016, 12, 5}, {15, 57, 44, 0}}]
%MyApp.Company{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "companies">,
 inserted_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-12-05 15:57:44>, number: 1000001,
 updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-12-05 15:57:44>}
iex(3)> Repo.insert! %Company{}
[debug] QUERY OK db=3.4ms queue=0.1ms
INSERT INTO "companies" ("inserted_at","updated_at") VALUES ($1,$2) RETURNING "number" [{{2016, 12, 5}, {15, 57, 45, 0}}, {{2016, 12, 5}, {15, 57, 45, 0}}]
%MyApp.Company{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "companies">,
 inserted_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-12-05 15:57:45>, number: 1000002,
 updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-12-05 15:57:45>}
```

Some notes:

- I set the sequence value to `999999` to ensure the next number in the sequence is `1000000`
- I added `read_after_writes: true` to the column because the value for this field is generated by the database, and without `read_after_writes` set to `true`, the field will not be reloaded after insertion and will remain `nil`.

Comment: thanks so much for your help. Are you on elixir team? I have one more question, look at the following [code on github](https://github.com/kostonstyle/relation/blob/master/priv/repo/migrations/20161203214117_create_countries_languages.exs) and pay attention on `countries_codes` table, would be not better to use iso as primary key instead of default `id`. Later, the `countries` table will use `countries_codes` for constraint.