# Postgres: Update primary key sequence for all tables

Tags: postgresql

I've manually imported all the data from production to my development server but I'm having this error. I've also read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342440/reset-auto-increment-counter-in-postgres) that fixes this issue but is only limited to a single table. I've imported around 10+ tables along with their data. This is the error:

```
PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "influences_pkey" DETAIL: Key (id)=(1) already exists. : INSERT INTO "influences" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"
```

Comment: Why don't just loop over 10 tables with the same command

Comment: The affected table already has about 20+ records.

Comment: So just set the primary key to start accordingly. You will be just updating the start point of primary key from 1 to 21 and next time db will start from 21

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here is plpgsql to reset all sequences (run in pgadmin or psql or any other client):

```
do 
$$
declare
 _r record;
 _i bigint;
 _m bigint;
begin
  for _r in (
    SELECT relname,nspname,d.refobjid::regclass, a.attname, refobjid
    FROM   pg_depend    d
    JOIN   pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = d.refobjid AND a.attnum = d.refobjsubid
    JOIN pg_class r on r.oid = objid
    JOIN pg_namespace n on n.oid = relnamespace
    WHERE  d.refobjsubid > 0 and  relkind = 'S'
   ) loop
    execute format('select last_value from %I.%I',_r.nspname,_r.relname) into _i;
    execute format('select max(%I) from %s',_r.attname,_r.refobjid) into _m;
    if coalesce(_m,0) > _i then
      raise info '%',concat('changed: ',_r.nspname,'.',_r.relname,' from:',_i,' to:',_m); 
      execute format('alter sequence %I.%I restart with %s',_r.nspname,_r.relname,_m+1);
    end if;
  end loop;

end;
$$
;
```

or use any other solution proposed at [How to reset postgres' primary key sequence when it falls out of sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243/how-to-reset-postgres-primary-key-sequence-when-it-falls-out-of-sync)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work, on mine at least. Using Postico and it's giving me this error:

    ERROR:  schema "_r" does not exist
    LINE 1: SELECT coalesce(_r.nspname,'.',_r.relname' ',_i,' ',_m)
                                        ^
    QUERY:  SELECT coalesce(_r.nspname,'.',_r.relname' ',_i,' ',_m)
    CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 18 at RAISE

Comment: hm - maybe Postico does not understnd `DO` statement?.. `_r record` is declared...

Comment: hmmm this is weird it's also giving me the same error with psql

Comment: @NellDavidS. sorry - corrupted code. fixed a bug - now should work

Comment: @NellDavidS. and thank you - fixed it in original answer

Comment: This still works just fine on 12.x, for anyone finding this in 2020.