# PostgreSQL PK sequence and Auto incrment problem after moving exisitng MS SQL DB to Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I moved my existing MS SQL database to PostgreSQL containing 160000 records, now I am having issue setting my Primary Keys auto increment. I have created sequence but it starts from 1 that create duplicate value, I want to start PK value from max value existing already in table for example if existing PK value is 8568 i want to start my sequence from 8568 and same for all the other tables in database.

Comment: In your [create sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-createsequence.html)  specify START WITH *<value>*.

Comment: In my case following Link works for me. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46883392/postgres-update-primary-key-sequence-for-all-tables