# How to delete all data for one and only one app in Django

Tags: django

I have a set up (Django 1.11) with several apps including OOK, EEK, and others irrelevant ones. I want to delete all the data for OOK while leaving EEK (and the rest) untouched. Ideally, I want all the primary keys to be reset as well so the first new OOK model will get 1 and so on…

Is this possible?

All I can find is `reset` and `sqlclear` which are both deprecated. `flush` removed all data from the database and thus not what I want

I do release that this is an odd thing to do, but this is the hand given to me…

Comment: As far as I know, handing out `id`s, is something that happens at the database layer, hence Django has not much to say on that. You can do this with raw queries, but that is probably not a good idea.

Comment: The easiest way is using `python manage.py flush` you could read the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#flush

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I get that but those are the requirements I have to work under. I am happy to mess with raw SQL and clearly will test this before doing it on the main database which will be backed up.

Comment: @Sardathrion my mistake I didn't read it correctly. So in my ears, it sounds like non-possible but I will be waiting for an answer by someone more relevant in this field.

Comment: @Sardathrion: well for MySQL you can reset the index with https://stackoverflow.com/a/8923132/67579

Comment: @PanosAngelopoulos No worries. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this behaviour dropping all the tables of that `<app>` and then migrating only that `<app>`. That way you'll reset the tables of the `<app>`. In `django 1.7+` you can do:

```
$ python manage.py migrate OOK zero //This command unapply your migrations
$ python manage.py migrate OOK
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-migrate

Comment: Would you not lose all data for OOK by doing this? Unless you have migrations for data as well...

Comment: Yes, but that's what he asked for "...I want to delete all the data for OOK...". Didn't he?

Comment: It's dangerous, because it can lead to unapplying migrations in other apps!

Comment: Also unfortunately it does not work if your data migrations don't have reverse functions. But it's not a big deal to add dummy reverse lambda-functions to data migrations.

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to replace the db, you could export the data you need to a fixture, then do some clever text processing in the json that is in there, say by finding all `ID` fields and replacing them from 1. Then reimport the result into a clean db?

The `id`s are autoincremented by postgresql, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5342503/1138710) you can reset the index sequence, but not even sure it can go back to 1.

But really what's the point of resetting the indexes?

Comment: Some of the indexes are used as serial numbers for items. Manager wanted them back to 1 or 1000 whatever was easiest.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be possible with django. However, it is doable with raw SQL:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

TRUNCATE OOK_table1;
TRUNCATE OOK_table2;
[…]

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

***⚠ Do take a backup of your database before doing that!***