# Prisma.io - Unique constraint failed on the fields: (`id`)

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, orm, prisma

The id parameter of the model I designed is autoincrement, but when adding a new record, I get a unique constraint error.

Model

```
model InventoryItem {
  id       Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  level    Int @default(0)
  position Int
  window   Int

  character   Character @relation(fields: [characterId], references: [id])
  characterId Int
  item        Item      @relation(fields: [itemId], references: [id])
  itemId      Int
}
```

Code

```
await prisma.inventoryItem.create({
    data: {
        characterId: myCharacter.id,
        position: 0,
        level: item.level,
        itemId: item.id,
        window: 1
    }
})
```

prisma version: 5.2.0
@prisma/client version: 5.2.0

Comment: What's in your database?

Comment: what exactly do you mean?

Comment: I mean is the `InventoryItem` table empty? Or does it have records in it? Perhaps auto increment counter is set below the record with the highest id and you may need to reset it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342440/reset-auto-increment-counter-in-postgres

Comment: no, I didn't set the auto increment counter afterwards. There is data in the InventoryItems table. I forgot to mention; This issue doesn't usually occur, but it's an annoying thing that does happen sometimes.