# Postgresql : Merge 2 similar databases

Tags: database, postgresql, merge

I have a requirement of merging two databases (Database1 & Database2) to a common database in Postgresql.

Database1

Table1

**Id  -   Value** (Id is Primary key)

1  -    a
2   -   aa
3  -   aaa
4   -   aaaa

Database2

Table1

**Id     Value** (Id is Primary key)

2  -    bb
5  -    bbbbb

I want my output as

*OutPutDatabase*

Table1

**Id     Value** (Id is Primary key)

1  -    a
2  -    bb
3  -    aaa
4  -    aaaa
5   -   bbbbb

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How are you deciding what the id should be in the merged database - does it matter? Are there foreign keys referencing these tables, and if so what do you want to do then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not my idea, but one I have read in the past.

[The source: Move table to new database](http://bytes.com/topic/postgresql/answers/421382-how-move-data-1-database-another)

```
pg_dump -d db1 -t table1 |psql db2

then psql and do

insert into table2 (select * from table1);
```

Answer (score 8):

First, load the tables into two separate schemas in the same database.

```
CREATE SCHEMA db1;
CREATE TABLE db1.table1 (id INT PRIMARY KEY, value VARCHAR(10));
-- load the contents of Table1 @ Database1 into db1.table1

CREATE SCHEMA db2;
CREATE TABLE db2.table1 (id INT PRIMARY KEY, value VARCHAR(10));
-- load the contents of Table1 @ Database2 into db2.table1
```

Then you can merge the two, by prioritizing db2 over db1.

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT ON (id)
  id,
  value
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    1 AS db
  FROM
    db1.table1

  UNION

  SELECT
    *,
    2 AS db
  FROM
    db2.table1) AS mix
ORDER BY
  id,
  db DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

I used the `migrate_pkey_sequence()` function defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38227173/545794) to migrate the primary keys of multiple tables (with the same schema but different values from different databases) to distinct ranges so that I could merge the tables.

This is the approximate sequence I followed to merge two databases, `d1` and `d2`, each of which has a table `example`:

1. Dump `d1` and `d2` to the respective files `d1.sql.gz` and `d2.sql.gz`. This is the command I used to dump:

   ```
   $ pg_dump --no-owner | gzip > d1.sql.gz
   ```
2. Create a new, empty database on a local PostgreSQL server.
3. Load `d1.sql.gz`.
4. Migrate `d1.example` using:

   ```
   # SELECT migrate_pkey_sequence('example', 'id', 'example_id_seq', 1);
   INFO:  00000: UPDATE example SET id = nextval('example_id_seq') + 0
   INFO:  00000: ALTER SEQUENCE example_id_seq RESTART WITH 1
   INFO:  00000: UPDATE example SET id = DEFAULT
    migrate_pkey_sequence
   -----------------------
                        4
   (1 row)
   ```
5. Record the value printed (4 in this example). That will be the start of the next sequence.
6. Dump to the file `d1-new.sql.gz` in the same way as above.
7. Repeat steps 2 through 4 with `d2.sql.gz` but use the value from step 5 as the argument to `migrate_pkey_sequence()`:

   ```
   # SELECT migrate_pkey_sequence('example', 'id', 'example_id_seq', 4);
   ```
8. Dump to the file `d2-new-without-schema.sql.gz` without saving the schema and disable triggers. This is the command I used:

   ```
   $ pg_dump --no-owner --data-only --disable-triggers | \
     gzip > d2-new-without-schema.sql.gz
   ```
9. Create a new, empty database.
10. Load `d1-new.sql.gz` and `d2-new-without-schema.sql.gz` in order. If everything worked as expected, the primary keys should be disjoint and not conflict.
11. Dump the database if you want to load it into a remote server.

Comment: As an added note, for migrate_pkey_sequence to work properly with foreign keys also make sure you have the keys set as ON UPDATE CASCADE

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to easily merge 2 postgres database using pg_dump & pg_restore.

In my case, it was easy as I use UUID identifiers, so there are no duplicated keys.

Export (data-only, excluding some schemas and tables):

`pg_dump --dbname=database_1 --username=${POSTGRES_USER} --no-owner --format=tar --data-only --exclude-schema=hdb_views --exclude-schema=hdb_catalog --exclude-table=app_configuration --exclude-table=migrations --file=/database_1.data-only.dump`

Import (changing role if necessary):

`pg_restore --username=$POSTGRES_USER --role=$POSTGRES_USER --no-owner --exit-on-error --verbose --dbname=database_2 /database_1.data-only.dump`