# Simplest way to merge two postgres databases into one?

Tags: database, postgresql

Currently I have two postgres 9 databases for two different datasources.

Database 1 is called **musicbrainz**, the main user is **musicbrainz** and tables are created in schema **musicbrainz**

Database 2 is called **discogs**, the main user is **discogs** and tables are created in schema **discogs**

I now need to do queries that involves tables from both databases, so I want to put all the tables in one single database. I'm happy to start again and load the data from the original data files but whats the easiest way to do this, specifically I'm a little confused between the relationship between username, schemaname and databasename and having a schema named the same as the database/ or user rather than using public.

Additional problem there are some tables with the same name in both databases (musicbrainz and discogs) although renaming one sense would be a possibility. Note the database is only for user by a single user (me)

**Solution**
I've decided to do it this way:

- Create new database **musicdata**
- Create new database superuser that matches unix username
- Create schema **musicbrainz** and **discogs**
- Set users schema search path to **musicbrainz**
- Import musicbrainz data into musicdata with schema musicbrainz
- Set user schema search path to **discogs**
- Import disocgs data into musicdata with schema discogs
- Set users schema search path to musicbrainz, discogs
- Check can see all tables with psql and \dt;

Working okay so far

Comment: not an answer but a suggestion : you can use `dblink` to access one database from another

Comment: possible duplicate of [Postgresql : Merge 2 similar databases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499227/postgresql-merge-2-similar-databases)

Comment: They're already in different schemas. Just load them in a single DB. Then `CREATE VIEW` wrappers that just `UNION ALL` the two datasources, e.g. `CREATE VIEW tracks AS SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM musicbrainz.tracks UNION ALL SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM discogs.tracks`. Or use `CREATE TABLE (LIKE ...)` then `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` from the two origin tables.

Comment: thanks but I think you miunderstood I dont need to union the data

Comment: I think dblink would have performance problems, the question was really about how best to logically organize my data and I think my solution does the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution I've decided to do it this way:

1. Create new database `musicdata`
2. Create new database superuser that matches unix username
3. Create schema `musicbrainz` and `discogs`
4. Set users schema search path to `musicbrainz`
5. Import musicbrainz data into `musicdata` with schema `musicbrainz`
6. Set user schema search path to `discogs`
7. Import disocgs data into `musicdata` with schema `discogs`
8. Set users schema search path to `musicbrainz, discogs`
9. Check can see all tables with `psql` and `\dt`;