# Changing the sequence value of a PostgreSQL Sequence

Tags: postgresql, sequence, restart, alter

How can I resequence the value start of a Sequence in PostgreSQL?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you done any research? Have you seen [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4678411/983430), or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/244265/983430), or a number of others?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can ALTER the sequence using the following code:

ALTER SEQUENCE  RESTART .

You can go through the PostgreSQL sequence manuals at the below link:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altersequence.html

Comment: Thanks Yousuf. Will try this out and go through the manuals.