# Auto increment id with sequelize in MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following model in NodeJS with sequelize and a MySQL database:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var User = sequelize.define('user', {        
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        ...
};
```

I am trying to add a new user to my databse with the below code:

```
sequelize.transaction().then(function(t) {
        User.create({/* User data without id */}, {
            transaction: t
        }).then(function() {
            t.commit();
        }).catch(function(error) {
            t.rollback();
        });
    });
```

After that, I am getting the next error:

```
Executing (47f19f7b-a02d-4d72-ba7e-d5045520fffb): START TRANSACTION;
Executing (47f19f7b-a02d-4d72-ba7e-d5045520fffb): SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
Executing (47f19f7b-a02d-4d72-ba7e-d5045520fffb): SET autocommit = 1;
Executing (47f19f7b-a02d-4d72-ba7e-d5045520fffb): INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, /* next fields */) VALUES (DEFAULT, /* next values */);
Executing (47f19f7b-a02d-4d72-ba7e-d5045520fffb): ROLLBACK;
```

And the error message:

```
[SequelizeDatabaseError: ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value]
  name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
  message: 'ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD: Field \'id\' doesn\'t have a default value'
```

However, if I manually set the id value, it works. It seems sequelize is trying to set a default value in the id field, instead setting an autoincrement integer. I have defined this field as autoIncrement in my database too.

How could I do this insertion? Do I have to set the id manually?

**EDIT**

This is my table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `birthdate` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uid_UNIQUE` (`uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: @Genzotto Even I am facing this same issue, But I didn't understand why did you give the initial value for the primary key(autoincrement)? and How did you do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678110/how-to-reset-sequence-in-postgres-and-fill-id-column-with-new-data

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You must be sure you're not even sending the `id` key at all.

I have done a quick minimal test and it seemed to work great:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize('cake3', 'root', 'root', {
    define: {
        timestamps: false
    },
});
var User = sequelize.define('user1', {        
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        }
});

sequelize.transaction().then(function(t) {
    User.create({name:'test'}, {
        transaction: t
    }).then(function() {
        t.commit();
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        t.rollback();
    });
});
```

Table dump:

```
CREATE TABLE `user1s` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
ALTER TABLE `user1s`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `user1s`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Comment: Your code helped me to discover my problem. In my table definition, I setted the id column as AUTO_INCREMENT, but I didn't set its initial value (AUTO_INCREMENT=1). Now it works beautifly. Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you checked if you have NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO?  https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/5493

Answer (score 1):

In migration, add this line of code:

```js
await queryInterface.sequelize.query("ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000000;");
```

Comment: Please add more details how to use this line of code