# Making Sequelize Increment Value Unique

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I currently am incrementing a column for order number values with the `increment()` function in Sequelize. ie: `.increment("order_no", { by: 1 });`

Occasionally a request hits my api at the exact same second and I end up with a duplicate order number value.

Is there any way that I can guarantee that the increment value is unique for an order number? Do I need to wrap the `increment` in a transaction? Should I have a random timed check after creating the number value to see if there is a duplicate? Not sure of the right way to solve this.

From Sequelizes documentation (https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-instances/#incrementing-and-decrementing-integer-values)

> In order to increment/decrement values of an instance without running
> into concurrency issues, Sequelize provides the increment and
> decrement instance methods.

However, while this appears to be working, I still get duplicate values out when being utilized.

Comment: MySQL has built in Auto Increment function .. why not use that as the Index as well?  It will not allow duplicates be default so no additional code required, just pass it a NULL on inserts, and you get the next value automatically.  Let the DB control the serials .. not the front end ..

Comment: If the serials are just numbers and integers at that,  Auto Incrememnt is the way to go, and if you need the value of the insert you can do a simple stored procedure to insert then select_last_id; so u can get the key u just created.  This would keep duplicates from happening because the server controls the values and will not allow a duplicate so its just built in, using a front end to do it is like re-designing the wheel.  Maybe i am missing something but I really dont understand why not use the built int feature.  If you make them the primary key too would be smart.

Comment: Let me know if this something you would consider, and I will type up an answer.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the generated SQLs.  I would like to analyze the problem from the database engine's point of view.  Be sure to include any `START TRANSACTIONa` and `COMMITs` around SQLs.

Comment: Do you have a separate class instance = object = table row -- just to track the current "order_no"?  Please also provide that class definition and the code that instantiated the instance.

Comment: If duplicate values in a column are not allowed, then then column should have a unique index.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to catch the error if duplicate order id occurs and retry the operation and generate a new order id.

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting this right,
You have an `orders` model/table that tracks orders. Each `newOrder` request that hits your API asks sequelize(Order model) to manually increment the `order_no` column. If two such requests hit the API at the same time, they insert the same value into your `orders` table twice.

So you want to add "unique key" restrictions to this 'order_num' column but this is not an efficient way to uniquely identify your orders. Whether you use `increment...by` or `increment/decrement` functions, sequelize will ultimately query the database with the same values.

In my opinion, you shouldn't be doing this.

Instead, add a `order_no` column, auto-increment the 'order_no' column. Sequelize supports autoincrement functionality for all dialects.
Check out this post: [Auto increment id with sequelize in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775165/auto-increment-id-with-sequelize-in-mysql).

To uniquely identify "orders", generate a random unique ID for each incoming order. It's better than trying to have unique integral "order_no".
Check out: https://dev.to/gulshanaggarwal/npm-packages-to-generate-unique-ids-for-your-next-project-1p3b.

With unique "order_id"s, You don't even need the order_no autoincrement column.

To count the number of orders in certain day, combine Sequelize's model querying methods like `findAndCountAll` plus `where` clauses based on a the `createdAt` timestamps.

You can do other tasks you need like sorting, counting the number of orders, finding the latest or earliest orders, etc.

These are well documented in the sequelize docs website.

Consider, redesigning your schema for better efficiency.

If this doesn't help, you can help us help you more by sharing the 'model instance' code, and the increment code in your API.