# Django Import-Export Import Duplicate key value violates Error

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-import-export

I'm working on a project with Django 1.10, Python 3.6 and PostgreSQL as the database backend, in which I have a model called 'Article" and I need to import data from CSV files. I have imported my first CSV file successfully with the following fields:
id, link & category
It's ID fields starts from 1 to 1960
then in next file, I have started ID field from 1961 to onward but it shows the following error:

> Line number: 1961 - duplicate key value violates unique constraint "article_article_pkey" DETAIL: Key (id)=(1961) already exists.

Even when i see my Article model in Django admin it shows IDs from 1- 1960

**Here's my models.py:**

```
class Article(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   link = models.URLField(max_length=255)
   category = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=Categories)
```

**Here's admin.py**

```
@admin.register(Article)
    class ArticleAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = views.ArticleResource
    readonly_fields = ('id',)
```

Comment: Can you show your resource class as well ?

Comment: do you mean views?

Comment: ArticleResource

Comment: `class ArticleResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Article`

Comment: try adding import_id_fields = ('id',) http://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

Comment: still same error!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157044/discussion-between-sandeep-balagopal-and-abdul-rehman).

Comment: I've had similar problems before, because Django was generating the ids itself (when you set id to be readonly). What I had to do was manually reset the sequence of the id field:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678110/how-to-reset-sequence-in-postgres-and-fill-id-column-with-new-data

not sure if that fits on your problem. but it might be a hint in the right direction

Comment: how can I manually reset the sequence of id field in PostgreSQL? please!

Comment: @AbdulRehman just check the link I posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have triggered that what's the issue :
Actually, the problem is PostgreSQL primary key sequential which is not synced with table rows.
That's why, when I insert a new row I get a duplicate key error because the sequence implied in the serial datatype returns a number that already exists.

To solve this issue we have to reset the ID sequential for PostgreSQL,
Here's the step by step guide:

1. Log onto the DB shell and connect to your database
2. First, check maximum value for id column of your table as `SELECT MAX(id) FROM your_table;`
3. Then, check what's going to be the next value for ID as : `SELECT nextval('your_table_id_seq');`
4. If nextval is the next number of Max value then it's right. **e.g MAX=10 & nextval=11**
5. Otherwise reset the id_seq for your table as:

   `BEGIN;`

   -- protect against concurrent inserts while you update the counter

   `LOCK TABLE your_table IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;`

   -- Update the sequence

   `SELECT setval('your_table_id_seq', COALESCE((SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM your_table), 1), false);`

   `COMMIT;`

Comment: This correctly identifies the problem I had. Django now comes with a tool to fix this: `python manage.py sqlsequencereset <your app name>`

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue, because I'd specified a custom `import_id_fields` field but hadn't excluded the `id` field.

I had specified:

```
    import_id_fields = ('code',)
    skip_unchanged = True
    report_skipped = True
```

But I needed:

```
    import_id_fields = ('code',)
    skip_unchanged = True
    report_skipped = True
    exclude = ('id',)
```

Bit of a noob error but this might save someone a google.

Ref: https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/issues/273

Answer (score 1):

i often run a for loop. This also updates my auto datetime fields:

```
import Article
for i in range(1, your_last_id + 1):
    item = Article.objects.get(id=i)
    item.save()
```

your_last_id may be `SELECT MAX(id)`