# Knex / Objection `duplicate key value violates unique constraint` when inserting

Tags: knex.js, objection.js

```
exports.seed = async function(knex, Promise) {
  await knex.raw('TRUNCATE TABLE posts RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE')
  await knex.raw('TRUNCATE TABLE users RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE')
}
```

and some seed data....

```
const faker = require('faker')

const post = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: faker.lorem.words(),
    body: '12 - 10',
    answers: '[12]',
    user_id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: faker.lorem.words(),
    body: '12 - 10 + 123',
    answers: '[12]',
    user_id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: faker.lorem.words(),
    body: '12 - 10 / 901',
    answers: '[12]',
    user_id: 1
  }
]

exports.seed = (knex, Promise) => {
  // Deletes ALL existing entries
  return knex('post').then(() => {
    // Inserts seed entries
    return knex('post').insert(post)
  })
}
```

A simple update method

```
export async function update(req, res) {
  try {
    const user = await currentUser()
    const params = req.body
    await Post.query()
      .findById(req.params.id)
      .where('user_id', user.id)
      .patch({ ...params, user_id: user.id })

    return res.json({ success: true })
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Something went wrong' })
  }
}
```

When I'm doing inserts in my tests, getting a 
`duplicate key value violates unique constraint`

Even when the test data created from seeds, has the id's of `[1,2,3]`, the insert complains the primary is already used. Why is this? Shouldn't the database be choosing the next available id?

```
exports.up = async function(knex) {
  await knex.schema.alterTable('posts', (t) => {
    t.integer('user_id')
      .unsigned()
      .references('users.id')
  })
}

exports.down = async function(knex) {
  await knex.schema.table('posts', (t) => {
    t.dropColumn('user_id')
  })
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Even when inserting with just SQL.. there are errors:

`INSERT INTO calcs (title, answers, user_id) VALUES ('tester', '[123]', 1);`

Results in a : 
`duplicate key value violates unique constraint posts_pkey'

The reason I'm not just using a knex `del()` call is because I am getting errors about deleting a table with foreign key references..

Answer (score 7):

When you insert the data from seed you are also passing `id` column value to the database.

That causes your `id sequence`of the primary key *to not increment* when you seed the initial inserts.

Now after seeding when you try to insert more data `id sequence` still returns ids starting from 1.

You should set your id sequences to correct values during seeding like it is instructed in this answer [How to reset sequence in postgres and fill id column with new data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678110/how-to-reset-sequence-in-postgres-and-fill-id-column-with-new-data)

Comment: Not passing the id column. There is something going on w/ how I setup the foreign / primary key. Going to update my question with new findings

Comment: You are passing `id` column in seed files. It causes `id_sequence` of primary key to not increment during seeding. So first insert you try to do in app conflicts with row with `id` 1.

Comment: @GN this should be marked as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

You should fix this part, missing **.del()**:

```
exports.seed = (knex, Promise) => {
  // Deletes ALL existing entries
  return knex('post').then(() => {
    // Inserts seed entries
    return knex('post').del().insert(post)
  })
}
```