# Java to postgresSQL. I am using SERIAL for my id column , can I make it replace missing value when I remove row and add a new one?

Tags: java, postgresql

I am doing Library  db , sometimes I need to remove books and add a new one and I dont like how it starts missing lower ids and it just goes one . Because Serial  just increade everytime . Is there a way how to do that ? For example different type of column instead of SERIAL

Comment: I'd say "live with it". Looks like a performance killer to me.

Comment: http://www.codediesel.com/mysql/sequence-gaps-in-mysql/
This might help (I know it's mysql, but it should mostly still apply; except for syntax)

Comment: You don't. Gaps in generated primary key values are expected and nothing to worry about. The **only**job for a primary key value is to be unique. It is completely meaningless if that value is 1,2,-6549, 42 or 464293. If you want to "renumber" the existing rows, you would need to UPDATE all tables that reference those values as well - something that will get ugly and complicated quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that will solve your problem but I suggest that you do  updating for all serial ids again.

So If you want it to be (1,2,3,4) so you can use this query :

```
ALTER SEQUENCE seq RESTART WITH 1;
UPDATE t SET idcolumn=nextval('seq');
```

source: [How to reset sequence in postgres and fill id column with new data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678110/how-to-reset-sequence-in-postgres-and-fill-id-column-with-new-data)

You can create a service that executes this query inside deleting books service, so after deleting books you will call this service to rearange ids

```
public void UpdateIds() {
// make a connection with your database and send query above to update ids
}
```

and in your service where you delete books, I suppose you have a service looks like that

```
public void deleteBooks(//some books ids to be deleted
){

//some code for deleting books by ids

// call the method above to update ids again 
UpdateIds()
    
}
```